# Positioning on an ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm working with and ExpandableListView which is quite long, so I added an AutoCompleteTextView in order to allow the user to search and position himself in the element (group) he is looking for and with this group expanded (just as if the user clicks on the group).

The pair of methods I'm using are:

```
mExpandableListView.setSelectedGroup(groupPosition);
mExpandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);
```

If I do this explicity before user clicks my search button everythig goes fine: my group is expanded and the listView position itself so that it is visible.

But, when I do do it by searching and clicking my search button (the logical way), I hide the keyboard and my group is expanded but the listView doesn't travel to show it (if the element is not visible).

In addition (I stored my last group opened position). if I click again whitout enter any new search (the keyboard is not shown), it goes fine again.

I think the problem may come from some focus stuff, but doing

```
mExpandableListView.requestFocus();
```

before the pair methods mentioned doesn't work.

Any ideas about this?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Okey solved, I was not clear about the relative positions maintain by Android in its ListViews, code for anyone who needs it:

```
 mExpandableListView.setSelectedGroup(groupPosition);
 mExpandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition); //Expanding the group selected, now the list has 1 more element
 mExpandableListView.smoothScrollToPosition(groupPosition + 1); //Scrolling to the content (the new element showed: the child of the group selected)
```